# Unable to share PDF in Social media

Tags: swift, pdf, uiactivityviewcontroller

When I tried sharing a text, I got all the apps that are available in my iPhone but when I try to share PDF, the only options that are visible are Mail and Whatsapp. Sharing on FB option was not there. I am unable to share the PDF in Whatsapp also even though the size is 86KB. I got the following error

"This item can't be shared. Try sharing some other item"

In the following link, it is possible to share on FB it seems.

[How to Share PDF file in all eligable and appear iOS app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30466912/how-to-share-pdf-file-in-all-eligable-and-appear-ios-app).

Can anyone give me some idea?. I tried the following code

```
func actionMenuViewControllerShareDocument(_ actionMenuViewController: ActionMenuViewController) {

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    if let lastPathComponent = pdfDocument?.documentURL?.lastPathComponent,

       let documentAttributes = pdfDocument?.documentAttributes,
       let attachmentData = pdfDocument?.dataRepresentation() {
       let shareText = attachmentData
       let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [shareText], applicationActivities: nil)
       self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you can share PDFs to FB. Btw you should try to save the pdf data to a temporary directory and share its url

Comment: Oh...Other than mail, whatelse v can use to share? @LeoDabus

Comment: As I said save it locally first. You can check the apps that would be available using QuickLook preview controller to preview the pdf and see what apps are available for sharing there

Comment: ok I will try. Thank u@LeoDabus

Comment: Btw better to use url resourceValues method to get the resource localizedName instead of lastPathComponent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28570627/how-to-find-file-uti-for-file-withouth-pathextension-in-a-path-in-swift/34772517#34772517

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055902/qlpreviewcontroller-change-title/43057707#43057707

Comment: Ya sure. Will try to use it and let u know if I find some difficulties

Comment: Another option to share it is to use UIDocumentInteractionController https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46456481/how-to-write-a-file-to-a-folder-located-at-apples-files-app-in-swift-4/46457518#46457518

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165458/discussion-between-suganya-marlin-and-leo-dabus).

Answer (score 1):

I used UIDocumentInteractionController instead of UIActivityViewController.The following code solved my issue in sending PDF to Whatsapp, Add to Notes, Mail,etc..

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Sample", withExtension: "pdf")!
docController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
docController?.delegate = self
docController?.presentOptionsMenu(from: self.view.frame, in:self.view, animated:true)
```